# Copy form data to clipboard using clipboardjs

Tags: clipboard, form-data

Is there any way to send the data from a form to the clipboard using clipboardjs?
I know I can send data from a textarea to the clipboard, but not several...
I've been googling for hours...

Thanks
Karlheinz

Comment: Corrected typo in main question.

Comment: You mean you want to copy multiple elements' data to the clipboard? Can you provide an example of the form's markup and exactly what you'd want to appear in the clipboard?